# Swift 2 - Sort Dictionary with NSDate()-Keys

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, swift2

I want to sort this kind of Dictionary:

```
var data = [NSDate: [String: AnyObject]]()
```

e.g.

```
data: [2015-08-29 12:08:29 +0000: ["foo": "bar"]], 
      [2015-08-29 12:05:13 +0000: ["foo": "bar"]], 
      [2015-08-29 12:11:02 +0000: ["foo": "bar"]]
```

should then be:

```
dataSorted: [2015-08-29 12:05:13 +0000: ["foo": "bar"]], 
            [2015-08-29 12:08:29 +0000: ["foo": "bar"]], 
            [2015-08-29 12:11:02 +0000: ["foo": "bar"]]
```

I tried:

```
let dataSorted = Array(data.keys).sorted(<)
// Could not find an overload for '<' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

and

```
let dataSorted = sorted(data) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
// Could not find member '0'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot sort dictionaries as they do not have order, so I use array in my answer instead.

By default `NSDate` does not conform to `Comparable` protocol. You have to use `compare` method:

```
let results = Array(data).sort({ $0.0.compare($1.0) == .OrderedAscending })
```

This extension can be used to make `NSDate` conform to `Comparable`:

```
extension NSDate: Comparable {}
public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
}

public func >(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedDescending
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

public func <=(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs < rhs || lhs == rhs
}

public func >=(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs > rhs || lhs == rhs
}
```

Then you can simply use:

```
let results = Array(data).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0})
```

Comment: `results` is of type `[(NSDate, [String: AnyObject])] instead of [NSDate, [String: AnyObject]]`. How can I correct that?
`let results = data.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }` is giving me the type `[(NSDate, [String: AnyObject])]` too.

Comment: @PhilHarmonie As @Kirsteins said, dictionaries can't be sorted (unordered collection). Therefore you have to return an "ordered collection" (`Array`) of tuples `(Key, Value)`.

Comment: @Qbyte yes okay, but after sorting an Array/Dictionary it should have the same type. If this is the only way to sort it, how can I change the type back to it's original type but with the sorted content? Or it the dictionary content always random?

Comment: @PhilHarmonie A dictionary is in most cases "random" since the order of the elements relies on the `hashValue` but it is NOT ordered by it. So it is the easiest way to accomplish it but you can also make a completely new data structure like `OrderedDictionary` which handles the ordering automatically.

Answer (score 1):

An (at least for me) easier to read solution without $0 stuff would be:

```
let kartoffel = data.keys.sort { (date, date2) in   
        return date.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12456503)

Comment: @Adis This does provide an answer to the question - it does not seek more information from the asker, nor is it a new question. It is a poor code-only answer, that may already have been provided, but not deletable for the Low Quality review queue. Refer to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue.